# Images aren't saved into my diskcache dir?

Tags: imageresizer

I installed DiskCache and set the dir to `~/diskcache/` in the root of my local web project.  When I go to the site and I get a process image, I don't see it put in the ~/diskcache/` folder on my local file system.

Comment: What does the diagnostics page say?

Comment: @NathanaelJones - I believe I got it working, but I have another question:  My images are stored on an azure cdn and their base url is `https://az824306.vo.msecnd.net/`, so with the AzureReader2 plugin installed, in my code, do I put the img src as the cdn url or do i use a local image url such as `/images/sample.png`?  Currently, I am using my cdn url, but when I do things like width=500, it has no effect.

Comment: Your image URLs have to point to the ImageResizer server. But you can't ask a question, say you fixed it, then proceed to another question - you need to answer yourself.

Comment: @NathanaelJones sorry,  your comment helped me understand... I did accrual create a question regarding my  other comment.

Comment: Then post an answer describing how you solved the problem.